# Modify pointer value in a function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm studying pointers and i'm trying to understand this code.

```
int main()
{
    int i=66 ;
    int *x;
    x=&i;
    f(&x);
    printf("%d",*x);

    return 0;

}
void f(int *x)
{
    int j=7;
    x=&j;
    printf("%d-",*x);

}
```

I'm expectin as output : 7-7 , but i get 7-66. I suppose that when i write

> x=&j;

in the function the original pointer now is setted to the direction of the j value and this is ok because the printf return 7- but why when i go  back to the main the printf return 66? isn't the pointer now setted to the j value of the function ? i know the values in the function are lost when i close the function but why my pointer is still setted to the i value in the main after i run the function?

Comment: Is there a warning related to the fact that `f()` needs a pointer to an int and gets a pointer to a pointer to int ?

Comment: The statement `f(&x)` takes the address of `x` which is already a pointer to an int. In `f(int*)`, change `x=&j` to `*x=j` to get the value from your temporary variable.

Comment: Even if `f(x)` is called, functions work on copies of arguments. Hence, the copy of x will be modified in f, but not x itself. `*y` can be modifed in function `f(int* y)`...

Comment: And you shouldn't be trying to return pointers to local variables (even if you don't succeed ;) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your function `f(int* x)`, you are assigning the variable `x` to the address of your local, temporary variable `j`. What you really want to do is assign the *value* of what is pointed to by `x` to the *value* of j.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int *x)
{
    int j=7;
    *x=j;
    printf("%d-",*x);

} 

int main()
{
    int i=66 ;
    int *x;
    x=&i;
    f(x);
    printf("%d",*x);

    return 0;

}
```

This can be run [here](http://ideone.com/F95fTY).

A second issue is the fact that you take the address of your variable `x` in the main function and pass that as a parameter to `f(int*)` which becomes a pointer to a pointer to an int (an `int**` not an `int*`). Remember that `x` is already an `int*` and can be passed directly.